# Travelling to Mexico with a US Visa but not coming from the US

Tags: visas, indian-citizens

I am an Indian Passport Holder with a US Work Visa. I am currently in Mexico and would want to travel to Colombia. When I come back to Mexico from Colombia, do I still need to go through the US or can i fly directly to Mexico from Colombia and not go through the US anymore?

Comment: Are you asking whether scheduled flights from Colombia to Mexico exist?

Answer (score 2):

Your right to enter Mexico visa free does not depend on which border station you are crossing. Since you have a valid US work visa, you are visa exempt.